# Java program is mixing up string variables

Tags: java

This is a myProgrammingLab assignment and I'm not sure where I am going wrong with it. The output seems to mix up the variables and I don't know why. I have included the expected output and what my code outputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name;
        int age;
        String city;
        String college;
        String profession;
        String animal;
        String pet;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();     

        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        age = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the name of a city: ");
        city = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the name of a college: ");      
        college = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter profession: ");
        profession = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a type of animal: ");
        animal = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a pet name: ");
        pet = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("There once was a person named " + name + " who lived in " + city + "." + "At the age of\n" + age + ", " + name + " went to college at " + college + ". " + name + " graduated and went to\nwork as a " + profession + ". Then, " + name + " adopted a(n)" + animal + " named " + pet + ". \nThey both lived happily ever after!");

    }
}
```

---

```
Expected Output:

Enter·your·name:·Enter·your·age:·Enter·the·name·of·a·city:·Enter·the·name·of·a·college:·Enter·profession:·Enter·a·type·of·animal:·Enter·a·pet·name:·There·once·was·a·person·named·Al·Smith·who·lived·in·Brooklyn.·At·the·age·of↵
43,·Al·Smith·went·to·college·at·School·of·Hard·Knocks.·Al·Smith·graduated·and·went·to·↵
work·as·a·Politician.·Then,·Al·Smith·adopted·a(n)·Pitbull·named·Toodles↵
They·both·lived·happily·ever·after!↵
Actual Output:

Enter·your·name:·Enter·your·age:·Enter·the·name·of·a·city:·Enter·the·name·of·a·college:·Enter·profession:·Enter·a·type·of·animal:·Enter·a·pet·name:·There·once·was·a·person·named·Al·Smith·who·lived·in·.At·the·age·of↵
43,·Al·Smith·went·to·college·at·Brooklyn.·Al·Smith·graduated·and·went·to↵
work·as·a·School·of·Hard·Knocks.·Then,·Al·Smith·adopted·a(n)Politician·named·Pitbull.·↵
They·both·lived·happily·ever·after!↵
```

Comment: your `age` is `int`, why did you use `age = keyboard.nextDouble();`?

Comment: Sorry that was actually a mistake. It was originally age = keyboard.nextInt();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is skipping reading the city string.

for age use

```
age= Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. This gave me a lot more trouble than it should have.